# PDE a priori estimate

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am not sure if this is possible, but can one find an a priori estimate in the $H^{1}$ norm for a weak solution of,
\begin{align}
-\Delta u +m u&=f\in L^{2}(\Omega),\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}&=0\text{ on }\partial\Omega
\end{align}
with $f\geq 0$, $m\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ $m\geq 0$ and $m(x)>0$ for some $x\in\Omega$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{N}$ bounded and smooth.

**Note on my attempts**

I have looked into throwing away the integral involved the $m$ from the weak formulation,
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}dx+\int_{\Omega}mu^{2}dx=\int_{\Omega}fudx.
\end{align}
However, this still leaves a mess as if I want to use Holder's inequality and Young's inequality on the RHS I end up with a negative coefficient of the resulting $\|u\|_{2}^{2}$.
\begin{align}
\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}\leq\int_{\Omega}fudx\leq\|f\|_{2}\|u\|_{2}\leq\frac{1}{2C^{2}}\|f\|_{2}^{2}+\frac{C^{2}}{2}\|u\|_{2}^{2},
\end{align}
and so the condition on $C$ is for an imaginary number. If I don't throw away the integral involving $m$ I still encounter the same issues as the RHS will still come out the same as above.

**Estimate for $p<N$**

Assuming $p<N$ then by Sobolev, Gagliardo, Nirenberg (SGN) we have that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|u\|_{p^{*}}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{2}$ with $p^{*}>p$. Since $\Omega$ is bounded it has finite measure and hence $\|\cdot\|_{p}\leq\|\cdot\|_{p^{*}}$. Now,
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}dx+\int_{\Omega}mu^{2}dx&=\int_{\Omega}fudx\\
\implies\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}&\leq\|f\|_{2}\|u\|_{2}\\
\implies\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}&\leq\|f\|_{2}\|u\|_{2}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{C}}\|f\|_{2}\sqrt{\frac{C}{2}}\|u\|_{2},
\end{align}
where $C>0$ such that $C\|u\|^{2}_{p^{*}}\leq\|\nabla u\|^{2}_{2}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{C}{2}\|u\|_{2}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}\leq\frac{C}{2}\|u\|_{p^{*}}+\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}\leq\frac{1}{C}\|f\|_{2}^{2}+\frac{C}{4}\|u\|_{2}^{2},
\end{align}
by SGN and Young's inequality. So,
\begin{align}
\frac{C}{4}\|u\|_{2}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u\|_{2}^{2}&\leq\frac{1}{C}\|f\|_{2}^{2}\\
\implies \|u\|_{H^{1}}^{2}&\leq\frac{1}{MC}\|f\|_{2}^{2},
\end{align}
where $M:=\min(\frac{C}{4},\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: You need a stronger hypothesis on $m$ to have any chance (your assumption does not exclude $m=0$ a.e.). Also, the GNS inequality does not hold in the form you used it - constant functions are countrexamples.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on why SGN doesn't apply? I should have made a note that any solution is strictly positive and moreover $u$ is monotonically decreasing as a function of $m$ (increasing).

Comment: I now see why SGN does not apply here.